# Question Appearing Twice in Favorites

Tags: bug, status-completed, bookmarks

One question is appearing twice in my list of favorites.

> [image]

Changing the sort order doesn't affect it.

I can't see anything that make this question unique, but none of my other few-hundred favorites are doubled.

Comment: Means you really, really like it.

Comment: I thought maybe it was some sort of unrecorded historic merge, but it seems you didn't favourite that question that long ago. You definitely do have [two favourite votes for it though](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/91103).

Comment: @Tim confirms my theory. You liked it so much you managed to favourite it twice :)

Comment: Theoretical cause would be a merge of 2 questions which were both favorited by you beforehand.

Comment: @TimStone Ah, now that you mention that it's stirring a memory... I think I did favorite this question on two accounts deliberately to see if this would happen when they were merged, but forgot about it and was surprised to see it now. So... `status-edge-case-I-deliberately-poked-then-forgot-about`.

Comment: Ugh, your favorites queue makes me cringe.  Although, there is [one particular question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain) which is quite nice and has good answers.

Comment: @Won't Don't judge me too harshly; like many I mainly use favorites as a notification system, not an list of high-quality questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These aren't the favorites you're looking for...

Comment: And what about [these](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197249/152859)?