# Question Showing Twice in Favorites List

Tags: bug, status-norepro, profile-page, favorites-tab

I was viewing [NullPoiиteя's favorites](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1723893/nullpoite?tab=favorites&sort=votes&StartDate=2013-08-08%2012:11:55Z&page=2) when I noticed it was showing an item twice.

Screenshot for those too lazy to visit above link:

[image]

The questions are the same, but for some reason it appears twice. So yeah...

Comment: +1 for the free hand cat!

Comment: Well, it was added twice as favorite same like in [this report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161881/152859), probably Nick handled just that specific case.

Comment: Nothing strange here, NullPoiиteя just *really* likes that question.

Comment: I like that the question that got duplicated was one about not needing singletons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow, we have two favorite votes recorded for NullPoiиteя on this question, a week apart from each other.

So, the page reflects what we have recorded.

I don't have the data to show if there we missed recording an unfavorite vote (most likely explanation), or that for some reason it failed to remove the record (an exception on the executing thread could cause that).

Now, this isn't harming anything, so I will not mess with the DB to fix it. But if NullPoiиteя  unfavorites and re-favorites the question, we should show a single record at that point.

Tagging with [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) as I can't reproduce a double favorite...

Comment: Challenge accepted! ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd = let the games begin. let the games begin.

Comment: NullPoiиteя confirmed it worked.